# Is there a way to create a new group from report results (instead of adding to an existing group)?

Tags: civireport, groups, reports

I see that I can "add contacts to a group" from report results, but what if I need a new empty group?

Is there a way to create a brand new group right from the report preview?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your group at **Contact > New Group** before you ran the report.

Comment: Yes, but the workflow is weird. What I'd like is:
1. Create report
2. Add contacts to new group

Not possible?

Comment: Not possible in OOTB CiviCRM. It may be possible if you have the coding skills but I can't give any advice about that.